# Multiplication of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I have the following problem :

```
w <- matrix(1:3,nrow=3,ncol=1)

mymat <- as.matrix(cbind(a = 6:15, b = 16:25, c= 26:35))
```

mymat

```
      a  b  c
 [1,]  6 16 26
 [2,]  7 17 27
 [3,]  8 18 28
 [4,]  9 19 29
 [5,] 10 20 30
 [6,] 11 21 31
 [7,] 12 22 32
 [8,] 13 23 33
 [9,] 14 24 34
[10,] 15 25 35
```

I want to obtain the following results in a matrix the same size as mymat:

```
       a  b  c
 [1,]  6*1 16*2 26*3
 [2,]  7*1 17*2 27*3
 [3,]  8*1 18*2 28*3
 ...
```

I've tried the lappy function but I am unable to get the results I want. Thanks!

Comment: ``help(`%*%`)``

Comment: `mymat*matrix(w, nrow(mymat), 3, byrow = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sweep()`:

```
sweep(mymat, 2, w, "*")
```

Converting `w` into a matrix of the same dimensions:

```
mymat * t(w)[rep(1, NROW(mymat)), ]
```

Comment: or `mymat*matrix(w, nrow(mymat), 3, byrow = TRUE)` (similar to your second solution)

Comment: or `mymat * rep(w, each = nrow(mymat))` (also similar to your second solution)

Answer (score 4):

**1) diag** Post multipy it by the appropriate diagonal matrix.  We can omit c(), although it won't hurt, if w is a vector rather than a matrix.

```
mymat %*% diag(c(w))
```

**2) KhatriRao** We could alternately use the KhatriRao product.  If w is the w defined in the question then `matrix` could be optionally omitted but we included it in case w is actually a vector.  Note that the Matrix package comes with R so it does not have to be installed.

```
library(Matrix)
KhatriRao(mymat, t(matrix(w)))
```

**3) mapply**

```
mapply(`*`, as.data.frame(mymat), w)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use also use `col` to replicate the values and then multiply in `base R`

```
mymat * w[col(mymat)]
```